# How to avoid writing multiple adapters for nested models in flutter-hive

Tags: database, flutter, model, flutter-hive

**Question**
I am trying to save a nested model in the hive and am registering multiple adapters for each object/model. Is there any simplest way to perform such action?

Can we reduce these multiple lines of code as all are depending on each other like:

```dart
class AlbumData extends HiveObject {
//example
  @HiveField(0)
  String? _listeners;
  @HiveField(1)
  String? _playcount;
  @HiveField(2)
  Wiki? _wiki;
  @HiveField(3)
  Tracks? _tracks;
  @HiveField(4)
  List<Image>? _image;
  @HiveField(5)
  Tags? _tags;
}
```

**Code sample**

```dart
// during initialization, I have to register multiple adapters
//otherwise can't save object
await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive
    ..registerAdapter<AlbumData>(AlbumDataAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Wiki>(WikiAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Tracks>(TracksAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Track>(TrackAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Tags>(TagsAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Tag>(TagAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<ArtistDetail>(ArtistDetailAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Streamable>(StreamableAdapter())
    ..registerAdapter<Image>(ImageAdapter());

    await Hive.openBox<AlbumData>(musicAlbumBoxName);
```

**Expectation**
As `AlbumData` is already extended with `HiveObject` so I am expecting something like this:

```dart
    await Hive.initFlutter();
    Hive
    ..registerAdapter<AlbumData>(AlbumDataAdapter()); 
    //Rest of the adapters should automatically attached
    await Hive.openBox<AlbumData>(musicAlbumBoxName);
```

**Libraries:**

```dart
dependencies:
  hive: ^2.0.4
  hive_flutter: ^1.1.0
 
dev_dependencies:
   build_runner: ^2.0.6
   hive_generator: ^1.1.0
```